# AWS: Boto3 configuring bucket lifecycle - Malformed XML

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

The following code should enable versioning on a bucket/list of buckets, and then set the [lifecycle configuration](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucketlifecycle).

```
import boto3

# Create session
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3Client = boto3.client('s3')

# Bucket list
buckets = ['BUCKETNAMEHERE']

# iterate through list of buckets
for bucket in buckets:
    # Enable Versioning
    bucketVersioning = s3.BucketVersioning(bucket)
    bucketVersioning.enable()

    # Configure Lifecycle
    s3Client.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration(
        Bucket=bucket,
        LifecycleConfiguration={
            'Rules': [
                {
                    'Status': 'Enabled',
                    'NoncurrentVersionTransitions': [
                        {
                            'NoncurrentDays': 7,
                            'StorageClass': 'GLACIER'
                        },
                    ],
                    'NoncurrentVersionExpiration': {
                        'NoncurrentDays': 30
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    )

print "Versioning and lifecycle have been enabled for buckets."
```

However, whenever I run this I get the following error:

```
  File "putVersioning.py", line 42, in <module>
    'NoncurrentDays': 30
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 253, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 557, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the PutBucketLifecycleConfiguration operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema
```

As far as I can tell, everything looks correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTlifecycle.html) you need to add Filter element, which is required as per Amazon API, and confusingly enough, not required by boto. I added the deprecated Prefix argument instead of the Filter and it seems to be working too.

Comment: Hah! Thank you.  I was pretty sure my syntax was right. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me:

```
        client.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration(
            Bucket=s3_bucket,
            LifecycleConfiguration={
                'Rules': [
                    {
                        'Expiration': {'Days': 5},
                        'Filter': {'Prefix': 'folder1/'},
                        'ID': 'id',
                        'Status': 'Enabled'
                    }
                ]
            })
```

To see an actual Schema, create a new rule in S3, and then use `client.get_bucket_lifecycle_configuration(Bucket=s3_bucket)`